# Find the length of the longest stick that can fit in the corridor?

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

A cube is given with length L. Inside the cube, there's another cube with a length of P. The distance between the cubes is D. So, the cubes create a corridor whose width is D.

What is the length of the longest stick that can fit in the corridor?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: If the cubes have parallel faces (please clarify) then I guess the longest length could be $2\sqrt{5D^2+L^2/4}$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I don't think it is enough to know whether sides are parallel. The answer is different if the cubes share a vertex or just (part of) an edge. Also, I think the answer depends on the ratio $P/L$, e.g., if $P/L<1/2$ and they share a vertex, then the longest stick would be $\sqrt{3L^2}$

Comment: @Patricio I took for granted that both cubes have the same centre and that $D$ is the distance between corresponding parallel faces. The OP should make that clear.

Comment: Correction: it should be $2\sqrt{2D^2+L^2/4}$.